How to change the inner components color of MUI DataGridPro toolbar?
I want to change the inner component color of mui toolbars. for example I have added columns here once I click on it a filter box comes with the default color of switch & other buttons. but I need to change them according to my theme. How can I change those?

const GridCustomToolbar = () => {
        return (
            <>
                <GridToolbarContainer>
                    <GridToolbarColumnsButton
                        sx={{
                            color: designToken?.palette.buttonColor,
                            '&:hover': {
                                background: designToken?.palette.hoverColor,
                            },
                        }}
                    />
                    <GridToolbarDensitySelector
                        sx={{
                            color: designToken?.palette.buttonColor,
                            '&:hover': {
                                background: designToken?.palette.hoverColor,
                            },
                        }}
                    />
                    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }} />
                    <GridToolbarQuickFilter InputProps={{ disableUnderline: true }} />
                </GridToolbarContainer>
            </>
        );
    };


You can pass those styles through columnsPanel prop of slotProps like this:
slotProps={{
  columnsPanel: {
    sx: {
      '& .MuiDataGrid-columnsPanel': {
        '& .Mui-checked': {
          color: designToken?.palette.buttonColor,
          '&+.MuiSwitch-track': {
            backgroundColor: designToken?.palette.buttonColor,
          },
        },
      },
      '& .MuiDataGrid-panelFooter': {
        '& .MuiButton-root': {
          color: designToken?.palette.buttonColor,
        },
      },
    },
  },
}}

You can take a look at this StackBlitz for a live working example.
You can see the list of available slots for mui datagrid v6 here.
